# Chinese localization

Tags: ios, localization

I've inserted multilanguage support in my iOS application via InfoPlist.strings files (en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings, de.lproj/InfoPlist.strings etc).

When I change language settings on my iPhone and run the application I can see localized strings at all languages except Traditional Chinese (Korean and Japanese work fine)! For this language I use zh.lproj/InfoPlist.strings folder.

I've double checked that the zh.lproj/InfoPlist.strings file exists in bundle.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Won't give an answer as I don't know the iOS specific bit, but zh-HANT and zh-CHT are both sometimes used to identify Traditional Chinese (the former being the currently preferred BCP 47/RFC 5646 code, the latter grandfathered in from when script identifiers weren't included in such codes).

Comment: iOS uses zh-Hant for traditional chinese and zh-Hans for simplified.

Comment: Do you advise me to rename zh.lproj to zh-hant.lproj?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that should be zh-Hant.lproj/.

Please double check if you have chose the correct one from menu that should be Chinese(zh-Hant). Simplified Chinese should be Chinese(zh-Hans) menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple language support in iOS app can be added by selecting "Info" tab under the project and then selecting the desired language. In case of Traditional Chinese, a folder with name - "zh-Hant.lproj" is created in finder.While for Simplified Chinese - "zh-Hans.lproj" is created.

If you rename the folder name from "zh.lproj" to "zh-Hant.lproj" this will add the localisation in project and it will work perfectly.

This solution also works in iOS 8.